# Stored procedure insert into table not working due to identifier not found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert all records from tableA to tableB. TableA exists, TableB does not.

Here is my stored procedure. This code works but it's limited to a **fixed** table name **tableB**:

```
USE [myDatabaseName]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoreProcedureFileName]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    INTO tableB 
    FROM tableA
END
```

However, I want to make tableB as a variable so I can pass it from C# code, this doesn't work, please help:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoreProcedureFileName]
    @tableName varchar(32)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    INTO @tableName 
    FROM tableA
END
```

Please help - why is SQL Server not recognizing `@tableName` in the select line?  Solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoreProcedureFileName] (
    @tableName varchar(32)
) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * into @tableName from tableA';
    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@tableName', @tableName);
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END;
```

Parameters can only replace constants in a SQL statement.  They cannot replace identifiers, operators, function names, or keywords.

Comment: Thanks Gordon!
In Oracle, this easy line works.  CREATE TABLE TABEB AS SELECT * FROM TABLEA   do you now how do I do this in MS SQL?

Comment: @Syntax_MM Sorry, `CREATE TABLE AS` syntax is not available in SQL Server.

Comment: @Syntax_MM . . . You can use the `into` clause in SQL Server (as shown here).  But the name cannot be a parameter.

Comment: @Syntax_MM . . . I there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

You must use dynamic SQL

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = N'select * into ' + @tableName + N' from tableA';
exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry!
In Oracle, this easy one liner works: CREATE TABLE TABEB AS SELECT * FROM TABLEA   how do I do this in MS SQL, MS doesn't recognize AS?

Comment: CREATE TABLE TABLENAME AS SELECT  is specific ORACLE feature. In T-SQL you can use SELECT ... INTO ... statement. for details and limitation see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15